# StringFormat does not work in Silverlight Control

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have a piece of code for a Text Box in a XAML File. The text box takes as input Numeric Value.Below is the piece of code:-

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Revenue, StringFormat=c0, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource NullableConverter}, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2"/>
```

However if I input 5 and tab out the input does not become 5 $. However, on saving the data in the page and loading the page the formatting is intact. Any thoughts on this ??

Comment: StringFormat=\{0:c0\} I think should work for you

Comment: @Chris W: The functionality doesn't seem to work in IE . It works in Chrome. Any thoughts on this ??

Comment: Wow, that would be interesting since SL is a plugin the experience should be the same across all browsers. Since it appears after saving the data I might consider how all data access in SL is asynchronous? Beyond that, I have no answer as to why it would work in one browser and not in another, there has to be more to whats going on I would imagine considering like I said, it's a Plug-in that's not browser specific. :/

Comment: StringFormat does not seem to work on user input, but it does when the applications reads the data. I think that your Revenue property is not a string, it should work with a string, if not, you can still StringFormat it on your set method of your property with ToString

Answer (score 0):

please remove the converter and try it, you should get it. should be something wrong with converter.

this is what I tried for Nullable Converter it worked.

```
    public class NullableConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return 0;
        else
            return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SL5 I think this is a bug, the StringFormat is not triggered when the binding is updated. For more details here is the  [MS connect issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/714760/silverlight-forum-stringformat-or-convertor-is-not-triggered-when-binding-is-updated-in-silverlight-5). You can check the workaround it might help you solving the problem.